# Deploy a contract to Ethereum via zkSync?

Tags: zksync

AFAIK When I deploy to skSync it "bridges" it to Ethereum.
Does that mean I get the Ethereum contract address and can start communicating with it?

Answer (score 2):

No, as it doesn't "bridge" its entire state, it commits just the proof of the state to Ethereum.

Comment: so my dapp would actually have to work with the skSync chain? Will my users be able to use ETH as the currency? will it work on their MetaMasks?

Comment: yes, your dapp is deployed then to zkSync chain. The users can use Metamask, Rabby wallets, etc. The native token is named ETH and the price equals ETH on Ethereum, the users must bridge it to zkSync.